# Trouble with sapply

Tags: r, datetime, zoo, sapply

Here is the reproductible example (at least on my computer)

```
a <- as.Date(as.Date("2012-10-01"):as.Date("2013-03-25"))
myFun <- function (x) {
    return(sqrt(abs(as.numeric(x-as.Date("2013-01-01")))))
}
```

`for (i in 1:length(a)) {
      print(myFun(a[i]))
    }`
works fine but

`sapply(a,myFun)` fails with error message

```
"Error in `-.Date`(x, as.Date("2013-01-01")) : 
Can only subtract from Date objects"
```

All ideas are welcome !

Cheers

Comment: Do you have the `zoo` package loaded?

Comment: @GSee it works fine for me ( even with zoo loaded). Can you add your `sessionInfo` please?

Comment: @agstudy it *only* works for me with `zoo` loaded. See my answer and try it after `detach(package:zoo)`.

Comment: I do have the zoo package loaded.

Comment: @Chapo And `packageVersion("zoo")`? Mine is 1.7.7. Regardless does the below work for you?

Comment: @SimonO101 zoo_1.6-2 is what I use at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work for me until I loaded the `zoo` package. Before that it was because of coercion issues between dates and numeric and not supplying an `origin`. If you try `detach(package:zoo)` and run:

```
 a <- as.Date("2012-10-01"):as.Date("2013-10-01")

myFun <- function (x) {
    return(sqrt(abs( x - as.numeric( as.Date( "2013-01-01" ) ) ) ) )
}
sapply(a,myFun)
```

I get back the same thing that I do when I load package `zoo`. The reason is that (on my R session) without `zoo` running, the first command results in:

```
 as.Date(as.Date("2012-10-01"):as.Date("2013-03-25"))
```

Results in:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(as.Date("2012-10-01"):as.Date("2013-03-25")) : 
  'origin' must be supplied
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does work but I'm not sure why... The zoo or base package should be able to handle conversion from a difference of dates to numeric no ?

Comment: @Chapo without `zoo` loaded the first line returns a vector of integer number of days since the epoch began. Then in the function we turn the date you want to subtract also into an integer using the default origin. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense but I was trying to do everything using dates instead of their integer representation. In fact, The base package doesn't handle direct basic operations on dates, hence my mistake.
Thank you for the answer.